# Python chart scale in google sheet api

Tags: python-3.x, charts, google-visualization, google-sheets-api, scale

I'm able to create chart into Google sheets by using python but I cannot find how to put the vertical axis scale to logarithmic for a column chart. It is possible manually with the graphic editor but I don't see how to do the same thing with a python program.
Thnaks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, unfortunately, it seems that the scale of the vertical axis of the column chart cannot be modified by Sheets API. So, how about reporting this to the Google issue tracker as a future request? https://issuetracker.google.com/

But, fortunately, when Google Apps Script is used, it can be achieved. In this answer, as a current workaround, I would like to propose achieving your goal using Google Apps Script and Python.

In this workaround, the scale of the vertical axis is modified using Google Apps Script deployed as Web Apps. This script can be run by Python script.

### Usage:

#### 1. Create a new project of Google Apps Script.

Sample script of Web Apps is a Google Apps Script. Please create a project of Google Apps Script.

If you want to directly create it, please access to https://script.new/. In this case, if you are not logged in to Google, the login screen is opened. Please log in to Google. By this, the script editor of Google Apps Script is opened.

#### 2. Sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the created Google Apps Script project and save the script.

```js
function doGet(e) {
  const { spreadsheetId, chartId } = e.parameter;
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheets();
  const res = sheets.some(sheet => {
    const chart = sheet.getCharts().find(c => c.getChartId() == chartId && c.modify().getChartType() == Charts.ChartType.COLUMN);
    if (chart) {
      sheet.updateChart(chart.modify().asColumnChart().useLogScale().build());
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(res ? "Done." : `Chart with chart ID ${chartId} and COLUMN chart was not found.`);
}
```

#### 3. Deploy Web Apps.

The detailed information can be seen at [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app).

1. On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "New deployment".
2. Please click "Select type" -> "Web App".
3. Please input the information about the Web App in the fields under "Deployment configuration".
4. Please select **"Me"** for **"Execute as"**.
5. Please select **"Anyone"** for **"Who has access"**.

   - In this case, the user is not required to use the access token. So please use this as a test case.
   - Of course, you can also access your Web Apps using the access token. Please check [this report](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#accesstokenforaccessingtowebapps).
6. Please click "Deploy" button.
7. Copy the URL of the Web App. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`.

   - **When you modify the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
   - You can see the details of this in the report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### 4. Testing.

In order to test this Web Apps, please test the following sample Python script. Please set your URL of Web Apps, your Spreadsheet ID, and your chart ID. The chart ID can be retrieved by ["Method: spreadsheets.get"](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get).

```py
import requests

url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"
url += "?spreadsheetId=###&chartId=###"
res = requests.get(url)
print(res.text)
```

- When your Web Apps is correctly deployed and Spreadsheet ID and chart ID are valid values, when this Python script is run, the scale of the vertical axis of the column chart is changed to the logarithmic scale.
- **When an error occurs, please confirm the settings of Web Apps again.**

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)
- [useLogScale() of Class EmbeddedColumnChartBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-column-chart-builder#useLogScale())

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very clear and it works very good !

Comment: @Jean Marc Canon About `Thanks a lot. Very clear and it works very good !`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @Jean Marc Canon I understand that your question has been resolved. But, if you cannot understand my English, please tell me.